# How to gain access to a specific folder and write a file into it using Scoped Storage

Tags: java, android, file, scoped-storage, action-open-document-tree

My app has a feature that exports GPS data in txt format into a shared folder (now accessed with `getExternalStorageDirectory`), and I have to switch it to Scoped Storage (API 30).
(As information, the app is the open source [GPS Logger](https://github.com/BasicAirData/GPSLogger) for Android.)

In the future I would let the users choose the folder to be used for the exportation, using:

```java
public void openDirectory(Uri uriToLoad) {
    // Choose a directory using the system's file picker.
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, your-request-code);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent resultData) {
    if (requestCode == your-request-code && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // The result data contains a URI for the directory that the user selected.
        Uri uri = null;
        if (resultData != null) {
            uri = resultData.getData();
            // Perform operations on the document using its URI.
        }
    }
}
```

This way my app will gain access to the selected folder.

How can I create a text file into that folder and write data using a `BufferedWriter`?

I know that maybe I can use something like:

```java
...
Uri fileUri = // Something related to the previous uri, but I cannot find the solution
OutputStream outputStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(fileUri, "rw");
txtBW = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
...
```

but I found nothing that works.

Comment: Wrap the `Uri` you get back in `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()`. Call `createFile()` on that to create a `DocumentFile` for a document in that tree. Call `getUri()` on the document's `DocumentFile`, and use that with your `openOutputStream()` code.

Comment: `a shared folder (now accessed with getExternalStorageDirectory),` If you change that to `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` you can write your files as before in a folder you created there.

Comment: Just letting you know they have changed the scope for android 11 +

Comment: @CommonsWare your small comment has been very useful to solve my doubts and to write the right code. If you would write the answer with some lines of example, I will be glad to accept it. As alternative I could post my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DocumentFile` is Google's somewhat clunky solution for navigating through document trees. The recipe for what you want should be:

- Take the `Uri` that you got for your tree and wrap it in a `DocumentFile` using `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()`
- Call `createFile()` on that `DocumentFile`, supplying a filename or other display name, which will give you a `DocumentFile` representing that document
- Call `getUri()` on the document's `DocumentFile` to get a `Uri` representing the document
- Use `openOutputStream()` on a `ContentResolver` to write your desired content to that `Uri`

Note that if you need long-term access to this tree, be sure to [call `takePersistableUriPermission()` on a `ContentResolver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/ContentResolver#takepersistableuripermission), passing in the `Uri` for the document tree. That should give you access to the tree and all documents inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

**1-You can create a target path like this (I'm targetting the "Android/media" folder)**

```
 private const val ROOT_FOLDER = "primary:"
 private const val ANDROID_MEDIA = "${ROOT_FOLDER}Android/media"
 private const val EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY = "com.android.externalstorage.documents"
```

**2- Create URI and intent object**

```
val storageManager = getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE) as StorageManager
val uri =DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUri(EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY,
                ANDROID_MEDIA)
val intent = storageManager.primaryStorageVolume.createOpenDocumentTreeIntent()
                .putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI,uri)
```

**3- Register activity for results**

for example

```
private val openDocumentTreeLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
        if (it.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val data: Uri = it.data?.data!!
            contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(
                data,
                Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
            )}
```

**finally launch the Activity for results**

```
openDocumentTreeLauncher.launch(intent)
```